# Where i can obtain client secret for my Universal app?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm following this guide (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465407) to implement push notifications on my app, but it seems to be outdated since I can't find the client secret as shown in this image: [image].

In developer dashboard (App identity tab) I've got only SID.

I also checked Windows Live Services site but there are only passwords and private keys. There is no client secret: [image]

Where i can find that exact client secret shown in the msdn tutorial?

Comment: There's a link right below the highlighted box to *Create a new client secret*. If you use the *exact client secret shown in the msdn tutorial*, it wouldn't be much of a **secret**, would it?

Comment: You misunderstanded me. First screenshot is from MSDN tutorial. Actual developer dashboard don't provide any link to "Create a new client secret". It also don't show any client secrets by default. That's why i am asking where I can find client secret for my application. I need it to authenticate cloud service and implement notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure also can't validate my app with provided SID (from Dev center dashboard) and password (from Windows Live Services site). i.imgur.com/VH1YIlo.png Maybe password != client secret?

The Application Secret is exactly what we need, some steps you need to verify/do:

1. Check the **Package SID** you filled in the Azure Dashboard, **don't add extra characters**, like Space character。
2. If you still can't pass the validation, please **generate a new password**:

   1). Click the "**Generate New Password**" button

   [image]

   2). Click the "**Active**" button to active the new password
   [image]

   3). Use the new password in your Azure Dashboard
   [image]

Comment: I generated new password: http://i.imgur.com/tA0D52x.png but button "Activate" wasn't present.

Comment: When i tried to use the new password in my Azure Dashboard the problem still exist. I also tried to put SID diferently: ms-app://S-1-15-2-17... or directly: S-1-15-2-17.... I also checked SID for extra characters.

Comment: @MariuszW I noticed the format of your password, so your app is a Windows Phone 8.1 app, am I right?

Comment: Actually it is a Universal App (including Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 Desktop app)

Comment: @MariuszW Looks like all things worked well for UWP app, but for legacy Windows 8.1 Universal app, I would suggest contacting with MS support to check your credential: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/

Comment: I found solution. The company's Azure AD account (Company.onmicrosoft.com) was a problem. To get the client secret It must be Microsoft account. Anyway thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The document is outdated, since you're implementing push notifications on your app, I assume that you're using Azure Notification Hubs, then you may refer to [Add push notifications to your Windows app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-push/):

[image]

> I also checked Windows Live Services site but there are only passwords and private keys. There is no client secret:

Be aware that the password is the client secret. By the way, it is important to associate your app with the Store, you can follow the steps in the new document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check that. So Azure Notification Hubs is now only-way to send notifications to my app?

Comment: @MariuszW, no, other services can also push notification. I didn't check that, but I think it should be same since this password in generated in the live services site.

Comment: I tried to send notification to WNS without Azure, using C# app but I've experienced strange problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845849/always-expired-access-token

Comment: @MariuszW, are you sure that you used a WNS service?

Comment: Yes, I followed that tutorial for WNS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh868252 but without success.

Comment: I checked tutorial for Azure Notification Hubs you provided. Azure also can't validate my app with provided SID (from Dev center dashboard) and password (from Windows Live Services site). http://i.imgur.com/VH1YIlo.png Maybe password != client secret? I associated my app with Windows Store using Visual Studio Creator but do I have to make full submission to store first to make it work? Including packages of incomplete app?

Comment: @MariuszW please see my answer